# Can you add an sms link to an email?

Tags: sms, hyperlinks

So when sending an email, insert link allows for types URL, anchor, email & phone (which is very nifty & opens phone app)
Is there any extension which adds link type sms? which would open sms app if user was reading the email on their phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like

```
<a href="sms:;+441234567890?&body=sms-text">this sms</a>
```

Hoping the URL link is not re-written by civi for tracking purpose when sending mass mailing

Comment: Thanks so much Pradeep It worked!

Comment: Can this asnwer be marked as Answered so that it can help others